# Where is the iOS kernel located in the filesystem?

Tags: ios, kernel

This may be a very silly question, but it has me stumped:

Where is the iOS kernel located on-disk? Is it even located on the filesystem accessible to a jailbroken iOS user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On production devices, the kernel is always stored as a pre-linked kernelcache stored at `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.kernelcaches/kernelcache`. On development devices the kernel is stored in its normal place, at `/mach_kernel`. On startup, the kernelcache is decompressed and run. [Source](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Kernel)

Answer (score 2):

The kernel can be found in the `.ipsw` iOS update files distributed by Apple. There is a `kernelcache` file in the [IMG3](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=IMG3_File_Format) format. Inside this is the kernel (and kernel extensions, concatenated to the end of the kernel base) compressed using [LZSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski) compression.

Comment: This seems to have been recently downvoted. Any reason why, Mr(s) Downvoter? :)